# Reskit mapping array without Key Paths

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I've been following the Restkit instructions on object mapping (https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) and I admit I'm still at a loss at how to map a JSON array - I find the whole Restkit mapping rather confusing in general!

I am attempting to POST an array, which is being expected in this format:

```
{
"messages" : ["message one", "message two"]
}
```

...nearly exactly the same as in the Restkit example for mapping without keypaths - except I would like to post all of the messages in one go as an array, rather than one message as a time.

I have this as my model:

```
@interface Messages : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *allMessages;
@end
```

Then I define the mapping like so:

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)defineMessagesRequestMapping {

    RKObjectMapping *messagesRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [messagesRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"messages"]];

    return messagesRequestMapping;

}
```

But I'm having no luck! Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Is this mapping intended to be used for sending or receiving data? Are you doing both? You would usually define the receiving mapping and then use `inverseMapping` to create the requesting mapping.

Comment: this mapping is for sending data. i'll have to look into inverseMapping... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just encounter similar issue recently, it's hard to say where's the problem. The way I debug this issue is just go into RestKit's source code, and check what request/response mapping it's using in the request actually, and make sure they are expected.